# Microsoft Azure OAuth Client Credentials Token gets "AuthorizationFailed" response

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-authentication

I want create APIM subscriptions through rest api, And was able to do it successfully by following this Microsoft doc, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/subscription.

And for Authentication I am generating a bearer token using ROPC grant type(My UserName & Password). Everything works fine with this flow.

But i dont want to configure my username & password in a application to get a bearer token, instead i followed Client-Credentials grant type(get token by client id & secret), i am able to generate token, but when i use that token to create subscription in APIM, i am getting a exception
**The client '0*****-*****-***e' with object id '0*****-*****-***e' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions/write'**

Is it possible to add a AAD application inside APIM AccessControl(IAM) to grant permission.
Or is this any other way to do this? or ROPC is the only way?

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, you can grant permission to AAD application (service principal) in APIM Access Control (IAM) by assigning it **`API Management Service Contributor`** role.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have generated one access token using **Client-Credentials** grant type like below:

[image]

When I used the above token to create **APIM subscription** with below query, I got the same error:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/subscriptions/testsub?api-version=2021-12-01

{
  "properties": {
    "ownerId": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/servicename/users/xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/servicename/products/xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "displayName": "testsub"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to grant **`API Management Service Contributor`** role for that application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> APIM Services -> Your APIM -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

After granting the above role, I generated the access token again and ran the same query as below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/subscriptions/testsub?api-version=2021-12-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

***When I checked the Portal, `APIM subscription` got created successfully like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to use Role-Based Access Control in Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-role-based-access-control#built-in-roles)